# Visual studio - set file location

Tags: visual-studio-2012

I have a VS project, but I moved some source, resource files to another location.

It's not easy for me to readd all again (cause of filled properties tab for custom build tools, etc.)

Is there any easy GUI way to change the included source file path? In XCode it's easy to do this, but I don't see any way in Visual Studio (currently using 2012).

Do I have to rewrite the xml build file?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have finally find it. Easiest way is to edit the xml file .vcxproj. I just have to manually find the paths (they are relative... i dont really know why Microsoft did this, it is so stupid) in that xml and edit it.